# How to convert form_tag in haml to erb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, erb

Hi this is my form_tag in HAML , getting errors when I convert it to erb,

```
%h2 Create New Movie

= form_tag movies_path, :method => :post do

= label :movie, :title, 'Title'
= text_field :movie, :title

= label :movie, :rating, 'Rating'
= select :movie, :rating, ['G','PG','PG-13','R','NC-17']

= label :movie, :release_date, 'Released On'
= date_select :movie, :release_date

= submit_tag 'Save Changes'
```

Below is my erb,

```
<h2> Create New Movie </h2>

<form action = <%= "#{movies_path}"%> method = "post"> 

 <%= label :movie, :title, 'Title' %>
 <%= text_field :movie, :title %>

 <%= label :movie, :rating, 'Rating' %>
 <%= select :movie, :rating, ['G','PG','PG-13','R','NC-17'] %>

 <%= label :movie, :release_date, 'Released On' %>
 <%= date_select :movie, :release_date %>

 <%= submit_tag 'Save Changes' %>
</form>
```

I am getting "can't convert Symbol into String" at around line 12.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `form_tag` helper.

```
<%= form_tag movies_path, method: :post do %>
...
<% end %>
```

Suggested reading: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag

Comment: But i am still getting "can't convert Symbol into String" at around line 12.

Comment: @shailbenq, could you add backtrace to your questions.

Comment: I did few changes to the code , the error has gone but i just see "Create New Movie" on the page.
<h2> Create New Movie </h2>
 <% form_tag movies_path do %>
 <%= label :movie, :title, 'Title' %>
 <%= text_field :movie, 'title' %>
 <%= label :movie, :rating, 'Rating' %>
 <%= select :movie, :rating, ['G','PG','PG-13','R','NC-17'] %>
 <%= label :movie, :release_date, 'Released On' %>
 <%= date_select :movie, :release_date, {:order => [:month, :day, :year],:prompt => true, :start_year => 1970 , :end_year => Time.now.year} %>
 <%= submit_tag 'Save Changes' %><% end %>

Comment: @shailbenq, apologies for missing the `=` sign in my answer.  It should be `<%= form_tag...`.  Please try the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks it works now, also if u have any links to tutorial for erb and haml please post it. I know few of them , but ur inputs will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be using RESTful resources and form objects:

```
<%= form_for @movie do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :title %>
  <%= f.text_field :title %>

  <%= f.label :rating %>
  <%= f.select :rating, ['G','PG','PG-13','R','NC-17'] %>

  <%= f.label :release_date, 'Released On' %>
  <%= f.date_select :release_date %>

  <%= f.submit 'Save Changes' %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

`<form action = <%= "#{movies_path}"%> method = "post">`

needs to be this:

`<form action <%= "#{movies_path}"%> method = "post">`

No need to put equal signs before an output happens in ERB. Or you should use the `form_tag`.